# Get method returns null

Tags: java, methods, null

So I tried to make a Hanger program in Java, and when I try to get to output a variable using a get method, it returns null. I first set up a Scanner object, then I set a String to the value the user inputs, then I use a set method to set the String to a new variable, finally, I call that new variable using the get method. It returns null, and I don't know why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hanger
{
public String word;
public Hanger(){}
public void setWord(String new_word)
{
    new_word = word;
}
public String getWord()
{
    return word;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input_names = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input_word = new Scanner(System.in);
    Hanger word1 = new Hanger();
    System.out.println("Please enter Player 1's name.");
    String name1 = input_names.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Player 2's name.");
    String name2 = input_names.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Are your names " + name1 + " and " + name2 + "?");
    String names_correct = input_names.nextLine();
    switch (names_correct)
    {
        case "no":
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter Player 1's name.");
             name1 = input_names.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter Player 2's name.");
             name2 = input_names.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Are your names " + name1 + " and " + name2 + "?");
             names_correct = input_names.nextLine();
        }
        case "No":
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter Player 1's name.");
            name1 = input_names.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter Player 2's name.");
            name2 = input_names.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Are your names " + name1 + " and " + name2 + "?");
            names_correct = input_names.nextLine();
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Let's begin! " + name1 + ", please type a word that " + name2 + " will try to guess.");
    String input_word1 = input_word.nextLine();
    word1.setWord(input_word1);
    System.out.println("Is " + word1.getWord() + " correct?");
}


}
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `this.word=new_word` in your setWord method of Hanger class